# Where's the best place to put an DJango Admin action which doesn't require a selection?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have some code to automatically scan the file system for new images and add new items as model instances. Currently I'm using the following to trigger the update:

```
def update_image_list(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    print "Updating image list..."
    AddMissingImageEntries()
update_image_list.short_description = "Update image list from filesystem"

class ProductImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = [update_image_list]

admin.site.register(ProductImage, ProductImageAdmin)
```

...which works except that I have to select an item to get it to run and it feels a bit hacky.

This action is related to the ProductImage so it feels right to keep it in the ProductImageAdmin area I'm just not sure how this could be tidied up?

Comment: Sure, it's a bit hacky but it's a great way to use existing "action" hooks to build something that works very easily. Alternatives would be a management command fired up by a cron job or a new ModelAdmin view (check out `get_urls`) that has a "Update images" POST handler which could be called from a `<form>` element in an overridden changelist template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a custom admin view with your ProductImageAdmin. And you can override admin template and add a button-link which will point to your custom view that would manage your image files. I would override change_list.html for the model and override {% block object-tools-items %}

[Overriding admin templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates)

[Adding views to admin sites](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-views-to-admin-sites)